# Numerical value of a name

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have come across a question which I am struggling to solve. The goal is to enter a person's full name and calculate the sum of the values of the letters. The first part required just the first name and the second requires their full name (I could get the first part).

```
def main():
    """To print a names numeric value"""
    name = input("Enter your full name here: ") #enters a name
    name.replace("", "") #removes all spaces
    str.lower(name) #converts all characters to lower case
    output = [] #creates an empty list
    for character in name: 
        number = ord(character) - 96 #ASCII code to make a=1
        output.append(number) #adds number to the empty list

    print sum(output) #prints sum of output
main()
```

If I type a first and last name it gives the wrong value. I think the issue is the space but from what I have understand about python the space should be removed at the start. Capitals seem to change the value as well
I made this thread last night and deleted it because I couldn't figure out how to get the code to print normally. It should be fine now.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i saw this question yesterday.

Comment: This expression is incorrect: `name.replace("", "") #removes all spaces` It doesn't clear whitespaces.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: No, I'm just reading a textbook to prepare me for uni which starts at the end of the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what you need:

```
def main():
    """To print a names numeric value"""
    name = input("Enter your full name here: ")
    return sum(ord(character) - 96 for character in name.lower() if character != " ")
```

Examples:

```
>>> main()
Enter your full name here: a
1
>>> main()
Enter your full name here: abc
6
>>> main()
Enter your full name here: a b          c
6
```

#### Discussion

The body of the code was reduced to:

```
sum(ord(character) - 96 for character in name.lower() if character != " ")
```

Taken one piece at a time:

- `sum(...)`

  This sums the contents.
- `ord(character) - 96`

  This produces the number that you want.
- `for character in name.lower()`

  This loops over each character in the lower case version of `name`.
- `if character != " "`

  This restricts the loop to those characters which are not blanks.

#### Alternative

A slightly different way of accomplishing the same thing:

```
def main():
    """To print a names numeric value"""
    name = input("Enter your full name here: ")
    return sum( ord(c) - 96 for c in name.replace(' ', '').lower())
```

This eliminates the blanks with `replace(' ', '') instead of with`if character != " "`.  Otherwise, it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
name.replace("", "")
```

should be

```
name.replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your replace call is wrong.

```
name.replace("", "")
```

replaces empty strings in `name` with empty strings, and then throws the result away. You want

```
name = name.replace(' ', '')
```

Strings in Python are *immutable*, which means you can't modify their contents. So string functions that perform some transformation on a string can never change the original string, they have to return a new string. But you can bind that new string to the old name, as I've done above.

It may seem weird that Python doesn't complain about the empty string given as the 1st argument to `.replace()`. But it's perfectly ok to do that. Eg,

```
>>> s='abcdef'
>>> s.replace('','-')
'-a-b-c-d-e-f-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing bad characters, why don't you just count good ones?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

# create a letter-value dictionary
base = ord("a") - 1
letter_value = {ch: ord(ch) - base for ch in ascii_lowercase}

def name_value(s):
    return sum(letter_value.get(ch, 0) for ch in s.lower())
```

Comment: Alternatively, we can skip the `import` and just do `base=ord('a')-1` `letter_value={chr(i+base):i for i in range(1,26+1)}` or `letter_value=dict((chr(i+base),i)for i in xrange(1,26+1))` for those of us still using Python versions older than 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Some point have already been made, but I'll reiterate.

```
name.replace(" ", "") #removes all spaces
miniscule_name = name.lower() #converts all characters to lower case
```

Lower case needs to be assigned, could be reassigned to the same name, makes no difference.

```
for character in miniscule_name:
    number = ord(character) - 96   #ASCII code to make a=1
    output.append(number) #adds number to the empty list
```